# Interactive plotting of a function of two parameters, one of which is found using FindMinimum

Tags: manipulate

Let's say I have the expression

```
Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]
```

The minimum of this equation in the range `{0, 180 Degree}` can be found with

```
FindMinimum[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x], {x, 0, 180 Degree}]
```

Now, if I wanted to get a plot of `x` (let's call it x`min`) at which the modified expression

```
Sin[x]^2 + h Cos[x]
```

reaches a minima as a function of `h` (x-axis), how am I to proceed?

Taking it one step further, if I have the expression

```
Sin[x]^2 + h Cos[x-y]
```

and I want to use `Manipulate` to change `y` on a slider such that the plot (`minx` vs `h`) changes with `y`, what form of expression can I use?

I think one can use `Solve`, but I am at a loss on how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, the following `Manipulate` expression meets your requirements.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    With[
      {xmin =
        FindMinimum[
          {Sin[x  Degree]^2 + h Cos[x Degree - y Degree], 0 <= x <= 180},
          x][[2, 1, 2]]},
      Sin[xmin  Degree]^2 + h Cos[xmin Degree - y Degree]],
    {h, 0, 1},
    PlotPoints -> 2,
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
  {y, 0, 180, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

Note: Because the function being plotted is linear, only two mesh points need be evaluated to draw the line. And since finding `xmin` at each mesh point is computationally expensive, limiting the number of mesh points computed speeds up the plot . That's why the option `PlotPoints -> 2` is given.

Comment: The [2,1,2] in the FindMinimum syntax, what does it indicate?

Comment: @SleepyPanda. `[[2, 1, 2]]` extracts the value found for `x` from the list returned by `FindMinimum`. For example, `{42, {x -> 1}}[[2, 1, 2]]` returns 1. Look up `Part` in the documentation.

Comment: Of course, `FindMinimum[fun, var][[2, 1, 2]]` can be replaced with `FindArgMin[fun, var]`